# How do I connect fileInput to ggplot in Shiny?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I have been working on this for more than 6 hours today, and I know it's a simple issue, but I can't figure it out. What I want is to input a file, and then be able to use multiple selectInput dropdown menus to change the output on the ggplot. Here is what I have so far:

UI:

```
ui = dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Apple Financials"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("file1", label = "Upload SAS Data:", accept = ".sas7bdat"),
    selectInput("x", label = "X-Axis Variable", choices = c("Sales", "Cash", "Assets", "Profits", "R&D", "SG&A")),
    selectInput("y", label = "Y-Axis Variable", choices = c("Sales", "Cash", "Assets", "Profits", "R&D", "SG&A"), selected = "R&D"),
    selectInput("scale", label = "Choose the Scale:", choices = c("Levels", "Log 10")),
    radioButtons("model", label = "Choose the Model:", choices = c("Linear Model", "LOESS", "Robust Linear", "None"), selected = "LOESS"),
    checkboxInput("ribbon", label = "Standard Error Ribbon", value = TRUE),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.model == 'LOESS'",
      sliderInput("span", label = "Span for LOESS", min = 0, max = 1, value = .75)
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    box(width = NULL, height = 415, plotOutput("plots"))
  )
)
```

Server:

```
server = function(input, output) {


   observe({
     data = input$file1
      if(is.null(data))
      return(NULL)

    df = read_sas(data$datapath)
    output$plots = renderPlot({
    ggplot(df, aes(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
      geom_line()
   })
 })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the input is a string, we need `aes_string` in `ggplot`

```
server = function(input, output) {


  observe({
    data = input$file1
    if(is.null(data))
      return(NULL)

    df = read_sas(data$datapath)
    output$plots = renderPlot({
      ggplot(df, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) +
        geom_line()
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

NOTE: For demonstration, we are uploading a csv file instead of SAS file

Comment: Thank you for your response! When I use aes_string, it then tells me the object 'Sales' doesn't exist. In the actual SAS file, it is denoted as SALEQ, so I think I need to somehow let SALEQ run as "Sales?"

Comment: UPDATE: I was able to render the graph. Thank you again!